How to Handle Security Violations and Correlate Session Tokens in JMeter for Temenos T24?
I’m running a performance test on Temenos T24 using JMeter, and I’m recording my script with BlazeMeter. During my test runs, I encounter a Sv 06 (Security Violation) error, and I’m unsure how to resolve it.
Additionally, I need to handle session management by correlating tokens to support multiple user logins. I’ve noticed that the session ID is stored in a cookie named JSESSIONID.
Here are my specific questions:
1.  Security Violation (Sv 06): What typically causes this error in the context of Temenos T24, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it in JMeter?
2.  Session ID Correlation:
•   How can I extract the JSESSIONID from the cookies and store it as a variable in JMeter?
•   How do I pass this session ID variable in subsequent requests to simulate multiple user logins?
•   Recording Method: BlazeMeter
•   Error Encountered: Sv 06 (Security Violation)
•   Session ID: Found in cookies as JSESSIONID

Any detailed guidance or example configurations to address these issues would be greatly appreciated!


1. Security Violation (Sv 06): What typically causes this error in the context of Temenos T24 - most probably it's due to missing or improperly implemented correlation

How can I extract the JSESSIONID from the cookies and store it as a variable in JMeter?

Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan. It should automatically handle cookies.

If in addition you need to store JSESSIONID cookie value into a JMeter Variable - add the next line to user.properties file:
CookieManager.save.cookies=true


Restart JMeter to pick up the change

You should be able to refer the cookie value as `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID} where required

Cookies and variables are local to the thread, you should see different JSESSIONID for each thread (virtual user) without any extra configuration




